# Getting attributes from Facebook Graph Object

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook api with PHP to get comments on a specific post by postID

```
$request = new FacebookRequest(
$sess,
 'GET',
  '/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/comments'
  );
   $response = $request->execute();
   $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();
```

the result when i do it with graph api is a file like that

```
{
 "data":[
 {
  "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
  "from": {
    "id": "yyyyyyyyyyyyy",
    "name": "someName"
  },
  "message": "commentMessage",
  "can_remove": true,
  "created_time": "2014-12-06T18:05:03+0000",
  "like_count": 0,
  "user_likes": false
}
],
"paging": {
"cursors": {
  "after": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZNVFUwTURJMU56Z3dPVFUxTkRjME1qb3hOREUzT0RnNU1UQXpPaTB4",
  "before": "WTI5dGJXVnVkRjlqZFhKemIzSTZNVFUwTURJMU56Z3dPVFUxTkRjME1qb3hOREUzT0RnNU1UQXpPaTB4"
}
}
}
```

the response graph object doesn't match any type of graphObject subclass.

i have tried:

```
   $graphObject['data'][0]['from']['name']
```

but the graph object is not an array

how can i get the attributes such as name or message from the $graphObject

Comment: Wild guess: `$graphObject['data'][0]['from']['name']` or some similar construct. Please always document what you've tried and what didn't work..

Comment: it doesn't work ,the result was an error:
Cannot use object of type Facebook\GraphObject as array

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0 according to the documentation you can use `asArray()` to get a basic PHP object, on which the above should work. Or you can use one of the other documented methods to access the data. There is no shortage of good documentation.

Comment: the response object doesn't match any subtype of graphObject.
i can't convert it to an array

Answer (score 0):

$object = $response->getGraphObject();

// User example

echo $object->getProperty('name');
echo $user->getName();

// Location example

echo $object->getProperty('country');
echo $loc->getCountry();

More : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/php/GraphObject/4.0.0